# Build a PDA that recognizes the following language

Tags: computer-science, context-free-grammar

Build  PDA that recognizes the language:
$L=\{x\in\{a,b\}^* \text{and } x\neq ww \text{ for any } w \in\{a,b\}^* \}$

How would you approach this?
 I was thinking I could do something with $ww^R$, but the problem is that I don't know if I am allowed to read the reversal of the remaining string at any point

Comment: Sorry I just fixed the thread.

Comment: Key hint: No matter how you split a string of length $2n$ into two odd-length pieces, their respective midpoints are always exactly $n$ indices apart.  PDAs are very expressive about midpoints of strings.

Comment: Actually, you already gave a CFG for this language in an earlier question you asked (Mar 4).  Why not just give some thought as to how to translate that idea into a PDA?  Also, why not link to the older question?

Comment: @ErickWong... I don't want this question to be left unanswered because I need to understand its solution. Please provide more help if you are willing to. Thanks

Comment: As I said, take a good look at the CFG you already have for this language from **your own question** http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2171178/understanding-the-context-free-grammar-of-the-following-language.  Any CFG can be converted to a PDA.